# Jquery Dynamically load JS script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

i am working on a project where i need to Dynamically  load JS when needed and i having trouble with that.
to keep things  simple here is an example

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function DemoSelect2() {
    $('#s2_with_tag').select2({ placeholder: "Select OS" });
    $('#s2_country').select2();
}

// Run Select2 plugin on elements
$(document).ready(function () {

    LoadSelect2Script(DemoSelect2);
    WinMove();
});
</script>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Country</label>
<div class="col-sm-5">
<select class="populate placeholder" name="country" id="s2_country">
<option value="">-- Select a country --</option>
<option value="fr">France</option>
<option value="de">Germany</option>
<option value="it">Italy</option>
<option value="jp">Japan</option>
<option value="ru">Russia</option>
<option value="gb">United Kingdom</option>
<option value="us">United State</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
```

I have in my JS.js script file this function to load the JS named select2.min.js the file is located on my folder named plugins and su folder named select2.

```
function LoadSelect2Script(callback){
if (!$.fn.select2){
    $.getScript('/plugins/select2/select2.min.js', callback);
}
else {
    if (callback && typeof(callback) === "function") {
        callback();
    }
}
   }
```

Note: I have already bundles to render Jquery UI and all the stuff.
The problem is that the script are not loaded
Update:
the problem is that Getscript is trying to load the file from :Controlername/plugins/select2/select2.min.js and not from :Root/plugins/select2/select2.min.js How can i solve that ?

Comment: does WinMove() expect select2?

Comment: the probelm is that the scripts are not loaded

Comment: @Apocaliptica61 use a relative or absolute (and not an application) path in the `$.getScript` or use the appropriate razor helper, your URL is wrong.

Comment: i tried with /plugins/select2/select2.min.js' and didnt work

Comment: the problem is that getScript is trying to load from :/plugins/select2/select2.min.js  and not from :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try the .done and .fail approach to see what error is happening. Maybe the "~" in the path is causing a problem. You can print out "exception".

```
$.getScript( "ajax/test.js" )
  .done(function( script, textStatus ) {
    console.log( textStatus );
  })
  .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
    $( "div.log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxError handler." );
});
```